# IOS app Crashes when ads load in Flutter Page view builder

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-pageview, google-mobile-ads

A page view builder having many pages and each page has 1 or 2 ads in it... On Creation of each page I make and load the ads and on dispose I dispose the ads...
Problem: it is working fine on Android but in IOS the app the crashing after 1 or 2 swipes...

I tested it by creating list view builder of 100 banner ads it works fine in Android but crashes in IOS.

I was expecting that the ads should load and show in each page of page view builder

```
The Code for creatingAd:
static BannerAd? createBannerAd() {
BannerAd bannerAd = BannerAd(
  size: AdSize.banner,
  adUnitId: bannerAdUnitID,
  request: const AdRequest(),
  listener: BannerAdListener(
    onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      debugPrint("Ad loaded");
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
      ad.dispose();
      debugPrint("Ad failed to load : $error");
    },
    onAdOpened: (ad) => debugPrint("Ad opened"),
    onAdClosed: (ad) => debugPrint("Ad closed"),
  ),
)..load();
return bannerAd;
}

this code is of every page of page view builder :

BannerAd? ad;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
ad = AdService.createBannerAd();
}

@override
void dispose() {
debugPrint("ads Disposed");
ad!.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

bannerAd == null
          ? const BannerAdDummyImage()
          : AdSpace(
              ad: bannerAd!,
              key: UniqueKey(),
            ),
```